# How to resize image without losing pixel qualityin python?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have an 32x32 image. I resize it for 512x512 in python, quality and view of image is not same when I resize it in paint.

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHhHK.png) [resized-with-paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iafp.png) [resized-with-python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvLXR.png)

What is needed to add to have same result as Paint?

```
from PIL import Image
im=Image.open('1.png')
im=im.resize(512,512)
im.save('resized.png')
```

Comment: those pictures differ in the interpolation mode that was used. please learn about them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
im = im.resize((521,512), resample=Image.NEAREST)
```

for that effect.

It is not really a *"loss of quality"* that you are seeing - it is actually a difference in the interpolation method. When upsizing an image, the algorithm effectively has to *"invent"* new pixels to fill the bitmap raster. Some algorithms interpolate between known surrounding values, other algorithms just take the closest value - also known as *"Nearest Neighbour"*. There are both advantages and disadvantages - *"Nearest Neighbour"* will be faster and will not introduce new *"in-between"* colours into your resized image. On the downside, it will be slower, look more *"blocky"* and less smooth.

It requires some thought and experience to choose the appropriate method.